# How do I know is there a value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df something like this:

```
lst = [[30029509,37337567,41511334,41511334,41511334]]
lst2 = [35619048]
lst3 = [[41511334,37337567,41511334]]
lst4 = [[37337567,41511334]]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['0'] = lst, lst2, lst3, lst4
```

I need to count how many times there is a '41511334' in every column
I do this code:

```
df['new'] = '41511334' in str(df['0'])
```

And I got True in every column's row, but it's a mistake for second line.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str(df['0'])` gives a string representation of column 0 and so includes all the data. You will then see that

```
'41511334' in str(df['0'])
```

gives `True`, and you assign this to every row of the 'new' column. You are looking for something like

```
df['new'] = df['0'].apply(lambda x: '41511334' in str(x))
```

or

```
df['new'] = df['0'].astype(str).str.contains('41511334')
```